# Core Data expressionForFunction:@"max:" with setPropertiesToGroupBy gives error

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am getting an error (iOS):
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions (logtijd is not in the GROUP BY)'

On the code below, am I missing something? I use a max: aggregate function so who do I get this error? "logtijd" - Core Data Date (NSDate).

Is the max: function available for iOS? See this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:

The aggregate function @"average" works!

```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tijden" inManagedObjectContext:self.context]];

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"logtijd"];    
NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

[expressionDescription setName:@"maxlogtijd"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:maxExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"starttijd", expressionDescription, nil]];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"starttijd"]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"atleet == %@ AND workout == %@", self.atleetGeselecteerd, self.workoutGeselecteerd]];

    return [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Comment: I get a different error trying to do a similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637611/group-by-with-sum-using-core-data